# helm: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: postgresql,

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, reportportal

I try to follow the [kubernetes install README of ReportPortal](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/blob/master/reportportal/v5/README.md)

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/reportportal-kubernetes/reportportal$ mv v5 reportportal

guettli@yoga15:~/projects/reportportal-kubernetes/reportportal$ helm install ./reportportal
Error: must either provide a name or specify --generate-name

guettli@yoga15:~/projects/reportportal-kubernetes/reportportal$ helm install ./reportportal --generate-name
Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: postgresql, rabbitmq-ha, elasticsearch, minio
```

Here is the [v5 directory](https://github.com/reportportal/kubernetes/tree/master/reportportal/v5).

What needs to be done now?

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution:

```
cd reportportal
helm dependency update
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a bit of a background.

Chart dependencies that are specified in the `Chart.yaml` should be download to disk before executing the installation of the parent chart.

This is done by [helm dependency update](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency_update/) which verifies that the required charts, as expressed in `Chart.yaml`, are present in `charts/` and are at an acceptable version. 
It will pull down the latest charts that satisfy the dependencies, and clean up old dependencies.